# Why is my SELECT ... FETCH FIRST X ROWS sending ORA-08103 Object no longer exists?

Tags: java, spring, oracle

We have several Java processes querying an **Oracle 12c** database.  We just migrated to this database from another database, so our queries could likely use some tuning.  We are using **Spring** `JdbcTemplate.query(String sql, RowMapper mapper)`.

Our problem batch Process `"C"`, selects data from `S_NAME.T_NAME` at a specific `RECORD_STATUS`

```
SELECT *
FROM S_NAME.T_NAME
WHERE RECORD_STATUS IN ('L',
                        'M')
ORDER BY PRIORITY,
         SUB_PRIORITY FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY
```

For each row, we update `RECORD_STATUS` to either '`N`' or '`O`' depending how it processes.

The process loops back to the `SELECT` until 0 rows are pulled.

We have 2 other processes which work relevant `T_NAME` data:

1. Process `"A"` - INSERT to `T_NAME` with `RECORD_STATUS` 'L' and varying `PRIORITY` and `SUB_PRIORITY.`
2. Process `"B"` - updates rows of `RECORD_STATUS` 'K' to `RECORD_STATUS` 'M'.
3. Processes `"D"` and `"E"`, which work `RECORD_STATUS` 'N' and 'O' respectively.

*The problem is that Process C is sporadically throwing **ORA-08103: object no longer exists** and I really don't know why.*  Subsequent calls to Process C work just as expected without the Oracle error being thrown.  **What is causing this error and how do I prevent it, or do I need to just compensate for it in my code and retry the query against the table?**  Research online against this error suggests a corruption, but that's not what I'm experiencing here.

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select * from S_NAME.T_NAME where RECORD_STATUS in ('L', 'M') order by PRIORITY, SUB_PRIORITY fetch first 20 rows only]; SQL state [72000]; error code [8103]; ORA-08103: object no longer exists
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:84)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:777)
>       at com.MY_COMPANY.DAO.MyDAO.getRecords(MyDAO.java:180)
>       ... etc ...

Comment: Is `S_NAME.T_NAME` a partitioned table, and if so, are there partition maintenance operations happening at the time you see the errors? I've had that particular error due to partitions being dropped and added before now.

Comment: @Boneist - no, they're not partitioned tables.  I also saw this as a possibility.

Comment: So s_name.t_name is a regular table then? (not a materialized view)

Comment: @tbone  It is a regular table, yes.  It is not a view.

Comment: What is the relationship between process `"C"` and processes `"D"`, `"E"`?

Comment: @APC - Processes D and E are the exact same SELECT calls as C except D looks for RECORD_STATUS = 'N' and E looks for 'O'.  Depending on the process, they do different non-table-related things with the data, then both update the RECORD_STATUS to 'Z' based on the identity column.  Rows with RECORD_STATUS 'Z' get deleted in 3 months.

Comment: The only time I've seen that error is when some other process was modifying the table.  Use this query to check if there are any DDL statements being run on the table: `select last_ddl_time, dba_objects.* from dba_objects where object_name = 'T_NAME';`.